# Movie from 80s or 90s - Professor Student relationship

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie i suppose was from UK because of their accent and it is about a professor in some university/school with a research about producing babies without having sexual intercourse from both man and female and eventually falling in love with this woman. This professor was old maybe 50s or 60s and the woman he fell inlove with was short-haired and the color of it was red/orange.

And one day a male student was interested and helped this professor to find a woman who can donate her egg cells to the professor for his research. And the other scene I remembered is this male student was interested with another female student and asked her if they can go to the beach and she answered yes.
This male student have a brown hair with 90s hairstyle and the female student was a blonde.

At the beach they have fun together, and when return to some beach house maybe the male was leaning on some wood and female student was at the bathroom. They were talking together happily when the man student said that he saw some more sand at her back and she didn't clean it off. Then the female said where and the male student comes to her and takes off her one piece swimsuit and started kissing her.

And the ending scene was the professor was talking something to the girl whom was the subject of his research at a beach and then they hugged and kissed and the ending credits.

The scenes were shot for what i remember was mostly at a university, the professor's lab where he does the research with machines, beach and beach house.

That's the only thing I remembered.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Comment: edited some descriptions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you be referring to [Creator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088960/)?

> Dr. Harry Wolper steals Boris, a new student assistant by promising him a co-ed's phone number. Then he hijacks new high tech equipment for his own research, confusing the other university researchers who can't see "the big picture." Harry has a plan, he wants to clone his dead wife, but first he needs an egg and a host. He mounts his search by stapling notices to every telephone pole in town from his bike, which is how he meets Mili. As the year progresses, he sees Boris' romance follow the same pattern as his own, twenty-five years ago.